# "Object '...' not found when referenced object is a nested function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Trying to nest functions with in a function to return a list in R after taking in a data frame. But running into a problem right away getting the error:

> Error in ------frqTbl <- function(df) { : object 'frqTbl' not found

Is there some way to define a variable that's a function before the function definition? Or is the nesting incorrect?

Tested with:

```
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")
test <- diamonds[1:100,]
mstrFnct(test)

mstrFnct <- function(df){      
    output <- list()  
    frqTbl <- function(df){
        fctvr <- df[sapply(df,is.factor)]
        logicvr <- df[sapply(df,is.logical)] 
        nwDf <- data.frame(fctvr,logicvr)
        if(ncol(nwDf)>0){      
            freq <-list() 
            for (i in 1:ncol(nwDf)){ 
               freq[[i]] <- as.data.frame(table((nwDf)[,i]))
               names(freq[[i]])[1]=colnames(nwDf[i])
            } 
            return(freq)
        }
        else{
            print("There are no categorical or logical variables in the data   
            frame.")  
        }
    }
    output[[length(output)+1]] <- frqTbl(df)
    rSqd <- function(df){
        y <- df[sapply(df,is.numeric)]         
        if(ncol(y)>=2){ 
            c <- combn(colnames(y), 2) 
            vrPrs <- paste(c[1,], c[2,], sep = "-")
            m <- cor(y, method = "pearson")
            r <- m[which(lower.tri(m))] 
            vlus <- r^2
            df2 <- data.frame(vrPrs, values)
            names(df2) <- sub("^VrPrs$", "Variable Pairs", 
                names(df2)) 
            names(df2) <- sub("^vlus$", "R-Square", names(df2))
            format.data.frame(df2) 
            return(df2)
        }
        else{
            print(paste("This Data Frame does not have two or more numerical  
            columns to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient(s)."))
        }
    }
    output[[length(output)+1]] <- rSqd(df)
}
```

Comment: Ok - I suggest you first of all separate the different functions. The definition of frqTbl() and rSqd() should go outside of mstrFnct(). In mstrFnct() the two others should just be called. Then please fix your variable names. R is a case sensitive language.

Comment: And probably you mean `diamonds[1:100,]` and not `diamonds[1-100,]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to define a variable that's a function before the
>   function definition?

No. **(see first code chunk)**

> Or is the nesting incorrect?

Actually not. You just messed up the variable names. **(see second code chunk)**

I suggest the following code to cover your example:

```
frqTbl <- function(df){

  fctvr <- df[sapply(df,is.factor)]
  logicvr <- df[sapply(df,is.logical)] 
  nwDf <- data.frame(fctvr,logicvr)

  if(ncol(nwDf)>0){ 

    freq <-list() 
    for (i in 1:ncol(nwDf)){ 

      freq[[i]] <- as.data.frame(table((nwDf)[,i]))
      names(freq[[i]])[1]=colnames(nwDf[i])
    } 
    return(freq)
  }
  else{
    print("There are no categorical or logical variables in the data   
            frame.")  
  }
}

rSqd <- function(df){

  y <- df[sapply(df,is.numeric)] 

  if(ncol(y)>=2){ 

    c <- combn(colnames(y), 2) 

    vrPrs <- paste(c[1,], c[2,], sep = "-")

    m <- cor(y, method = "pearson")

    r <- m[which(lower.tri(m))] 

    vlus <- r^2

    df2 <- data.frame(vrPrs, vlus)

    names(df2) <- sub("^vrPrs$", "Variable Pairs", 
                      names(df2)) 
    names(df2) <- sub("^vlus$", "R-Square", names(df2))


    format.data.frame(df2) 
    return(df2)

  }
  else{
    print(paste("This Data Frame does not have two or more numerical  
            columns to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient(s)."))
  }
}

mstrFnct <- function(df){

  output <- list()
  output[[length(output)+1]] <- frqTbl(df)
  output[[length(output)+1]] <- rSqd(df)

  return(output)
}

data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")
test <- diamonds[1:100,]
mstrFnct(test)
```

But you could also pack the function definitions into the master function. Like this:

```
mstrFnct <- function(df){

  # create output list
  output <- list()

  # define function frqTbl()
  frqTbl <- function(df){

    fctvr <- df[sapply(df,is.factor)]
    logicvr <- df[sapply(df,is.logical)] 
    nwDf <- data.frame(fctvr,logicvr)

    if(ncol(nwDf)>0){ 

      freq <-list() 
      for (i in 1:ncol(nwDf)){ 

        freq[[i]] <- as.data.frame(table((nwDf)[,i]))
        names(freq[[i]])[1]=colnames(nwDf[i])
      } 
      return(freq)
    }
    else{
      print("There are no categorical or logical variables in the data   
          frame.")  
    }
  }

  # call function frqTbl() and store result in list
  output[[length(output)+1]] <- frqTbl(df)

  # define function rSqd()
  rSqd <- function(df){

    y <- df[sapply(df,is.numeric)] 

    if(ncol(y)>=2){ 

      c <- combn(colnames(y), 2) 

      vrPrs <- paste(c[1,], c[2,], sep = "-")

      m <- cor(y, method = "pearson")

      r <- m[which(lower.tri(m))] 

      vlus <- r^2

      df2 <- data.frame(vrPrs, vlus)

      names(df2) <- sub("^vrPrs$", "Variable Pairs", 
                        names(df2)) 
      names(df2) <- sub("^vlus$", "R-Square", names(df2))


      format.data.frame(df2) 
      return(df2)

    }
    else{
      print(paste("This Data Frame does not have two or more numerical  
            columns to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient(s)."))
    }
  }

  # call function rSqd() and store result in list
  output[[length(output)+1]] <- rSqd(df)

  return(output)
}

data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")
test <- diamonds[1:100,]
mstrFnct(test)
```

Comment: Was it really just the variables that were messed up in my original code that, after fixing, you got your 2nd chunk of code to work? I'm trying to add additional nested functions that work outside the mstrFnct, but when I add them it's just returning output up to the summ(). eg:

Comment: I resolved the issue in my last problem: I didn't realize that return() only brings back the first instance of it. Regardless, thank you for your answer and the comments critiquing my initial errors.